# How to start object mapping mode in jubula?

Tags: swing, testing, eclipse-plugin, automated-tests, jubula

I am trying jubula to automate test cases. Start object mapping mode is not clickable. I created test case and added component but I don't map with aut(application under test).

Answer (score 0):

First you must connect to an AUT agent (I guess Embedded will do it for you) and then start an AUT. It has to appear in the Running AUTs view.

Only then you can click on the mapping button.

PS.: I recommend you raise questions like these on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ instead. Some might find this question off-topic here.

Comment: I have connected to UAT and started. but mapping button is not still clickable.

Comment: I did't know this site(sqa.stackexchange). Thank you.